# Passing props to <Outlet /> when nesting routes in React Router v6?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

**How can I pass `props` to the `<Outlet />` component when I am nesting routes?**

```
// Parent Comp 
{
  const [format, setFormat] = useState('rgb');
  const color = [hex, rgb, rgba]
  
  // ...

  return (
    <PaletteNavBar changeFormat={setFormat}/>

      {colorId ? <ColorBoxes /> : <Outlet color={color[format]} />}

      // setFormat(hex) is called down here
    <PaletteFooter />;
  )
}
```

I don't want to pass them via URL parameters.

Comment: And what is the `Outlet` rendering that you really want to pass a `color` prop value to? See [below comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70027979/passing-props-to-outlet-when-nestining-routes-in-react-router-v6/70028452#comment123791905_70028452) as to the likely use of the React Context API to pass values down to distant children without needing to drill them through all the intermediate components.

Comment: `ColorBoxes` will render a palette of 20 colors, and `Outlet` will render a single color with different shades, and format is needed to allow you to copy the color with your selected format

Comment: `Outlet` components render only `Route` components. We need more context. Can you update and provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: You answered my question by "`Outlet` components render only `Route` components.", and "React Context API". It seems like I miss understood `Outlet`, and  I should keep track of the format using Context API. Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `Outlet` doesn't take any props, nor will it pass anything as props on to what it renders. It is simply an output for children routes of a component.

Pass them to the component rendered by the Route, it's the Route that is rendered into the Outlet.

Example:

```
const Layout = () => (
  <div className="super-style">
    <h1>My super awesome layout container</h1>
    <Outlet /> // <-- children routes rendered here
  </div>
);
```

...

```
<Routes>
  <Route element={<Layout />}>
    <Route // <-- rendered into Outlet of Layout
      path="..."
      element={<Component foo="bar" />} // <-- pass props to component here
    />
    ... other routes for outlet
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

However, the `Outlet` *does* provide a React context that can be accessed via the [useOutletContext](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#useoutletcontext) hook since it's a common enough pattern for parent routes to manage some state or value to be shared with children routes.

```
const Layout = () => (
  const [foo, setFoo] = React.useState();

  <div className="super-style">
    <h1>My super awesome layout container</h1>
    <Outlet context={[foo, setFoo]} /> // <-- pass context value
  </div>
);
```

...

```
<Routes>
  <Route element={<Layout />}>
    <Route path="..." element={<Component />} />
    ... other routes for outlet
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

...

```
import { useOutletContext } from 'react-router-dom';

const Component = () => {
  const [foo, setFoo] = useOutletContext(); // <-- access context value

  ...
};
```

Comment: But, What if I needed to pass a value that is based on an Input tag inside the parent component? I mean that the value needs to be assigned inside the parent component?

Sorry if I didn't make that clear.

Comment: @Haitham6373 If it's the parent component then wouldn't it just pass it normally as a prop to the child component it is rendering? Do you have a more representative example for what you are trying to accomplish? It sounds like you are attempting to accomplish something the React Context API exists for, i.e. passing values to descendant components without explicitly drilling the props to them.

Comment: I did update the example, can please check it again

Answer (score 3):

you better use outlet context to pass the props from parent to nested routes

https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#useoutletcontext

Comment: This context API works for my case when I needed to pass params from PrivateRoute to its children components. Thanks.